# Receive URL by NSService, Drop on App-Icon or NSView: how to determine if it's already in sandbox?

Tags: macos, cocoa, appstore-sandbox

The [App Sandbox Design Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW16) suggests saving all Security Scoped Bookmarks into `NSUserDefaults`.

When the user drops for example his home directory onto our app, we'll save that SSB. After a while, the user may drop something inside his home directory on to the app. How do I find out if I have to store this `NSURL` again as SSB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain a cache as pairs of absolute path (remove any symlinks), security scoped bookmark.

When adding a new item if it is a child on any of the existing ones its not needed. Otherwise add it and if its the parent of one or more remove them.